# How do I map color to temperature?

Tags: thermal-radiation

Following up to [Do burning red coals and red-hot iron have the same temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76684/do-burning-red-coals-and-red-hot-iron-have-the-same-temperature) and [Are Colors Emitted at Specific Temperatures?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/are-colors-emitted-at-specific-temperatures), how do I determine the temperature of the object by the color of the light it is emitting?

E.g., a *picture* with different temperatures written in different colors would be nice.

Note that this would have to take eye sensitivity to different temperatures into account as well as the emission spectrum.

Comment: You mean, something like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Blackbody-colours-vertical.svg, or this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PlanckianLocus.png

Comment: @DmitryBrant: yes - but does that picture account for eye sensitivity?

Comment: The pictures refer to wavelengths of light. How any individual organism perceives the light is entirely subjective. What would it mean for such a chart to account for eye sensitivity? It's like asking if the chart could account for color-blindness.  Are you asking what range of wavelengths is visible to the human eye? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum

Comment: @DmitryBrant: humans, in general, have a similar eye sensitivity to the same colors.

Comment: They do indeed. However, for a number of reasons, it's totally impractical to use the human eye as a measurement device for black-body temperature, except for a *very* rough approximation.

Comment: @sds The pictures do directly relate to the human eye. Black body radiation for a given temperature is a continuous spectrum. This can be mapped to 3D space by passing it through the human visual system....

Comment: continued... In the first image that is done by drawing the pixels in a color equivalent to how we would see the spectrum (strictly speaking by defining RGB values that give a spectrum that is very different, but to the human eye looks the same); in the second this is done as well, but additionally it is shown within a larger space, which is a two dimensional section of our 3D space of colors: XYZ is a color space whose coordinates are directly based on the cone responses. What you see is essentially the intersection of that space with a plane of constant brightness.